# Why does `overflow-x: auto;` behave strangely inside `flex-direction: row;` ancestor?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, overflow, blazor-server-side

I have read 10+ other questions about horizontally scrolling tables, but nothing seems to apply to this issue.

With the default Blazor Server template in a new project - built with Bootstrap 4 - browser window scrollability isn't eliminated when using a responsive table.

Bootstrap's `.table-responsive` - which uses `overflow-x: auto;` is designed to work when its parent has a fixed width. Even with that in place, the horizontal scroll on the window is still there.

**Reduced Case**

This example uses Bootstrap's underlying CSS - `overflow-x: auto;` - to be as reduced a test case as possible. The issue may be with how `flex` works. There are multiple `div`s between the `flex` parent and the `overflow-x: auto;`.

Open the following Codeply view, reduce the width of your browser to its smallest width, and notice that the table scrolls but the window also still scrolls.

https://www.codeply.com/v/FbZndMn15v

**Code**

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LayoutTest</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <app style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">LayoutTest</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link active">
                            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="counter" class="nav-link">
                            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="fetchdata" class="nav-link">
                            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="width: 500px;">
            <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to have nothing to do with the table. It's the 500px width that's set on the outer div along with the padding and contents of the sidebar

Comment: @Zim `overflow-x: auto;` needs a parent with a specified width in order for it to work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to hide `overflow-x` on the parent `flex` element and set `min-width` to 0 for its child that is an ancestor of the element that should overflow.

https://www.codeply.com/v/k63CkWZrRH

**Code**

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LayoutTest</title>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body>
    <app style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">LayoutTest</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link active">
                            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="counter" class="nav-link">
                            <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-3">
                        <a href="fetchdata" class="nav-link">
                            <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="min-width: 0;">
            <div style="overflow-x: auto;">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                            <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                            <td>Cell</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app>
</body>
</html>
```